# How do i make bot edit its message using Hikari? (Discord)

Tags: python, discord, bots

I want to ask if i can edit the message of my bot. Im using Hikari (lightbulb).
This is what i want to happen:
• Uses /ping
• Bot replies with a "Pong!"
• Sleeps for a second
• Bot edits the message
• Result: "Ping?"

Comment: I swear no one knows how to use hikari/lightbulb, I regret choosing them for my bot

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is `await ctx.edit_last_response("New message content")`

[Documentation](https://hikari-lightbulb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_references/context.html#lightbulb.context.base.Context.edit_last_response)